# Query works in phpMyAdmin, fails to return sum()-values in PHP, caused by date-filter?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to collect a sum of numbers from multiple rows like so:
(Simplified version to isolate the problem)

```
"SELECT sum( field_voeding_vlees_value )
FROM content_field_date
LEFT JOIN content_type_expense ON content_field_date.nid = content_type_expense.nid
WHERE addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) >= '2011-11-01'
AND addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) <= '2011-11-31'"
```

This query works perfectly in phpMyAdmin, returns something like:

**sum(field_voeding_vlees_value)**

*115.12*

However, when I run it in a php-script(in a custom module in drupal) with this code:

```
$result_query_totals = db_query("SELECT sum( field_voeding_vlees_value )
FROM content_field_date
LEFT JOIN content_type_expense ON content_field_date.nid = content_type_expense.nid
WHERE addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) >= '2011-11-01'
AND addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) <= '2011-11-31'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result_query_totals);
print_r($row);
```

This outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sum( field_voeding_vlees_value )] => 
)
```

Also tried selecting normal values, problem persists, however if I remove the WHERE part which filters on the dates(strings transformed to dates tbh) the query works fine?

Thoughts?

Comment: just as an advice make your `field_date_value` a date or a datetime, you might not realize the problem if you have only few rows in that table, but increase the number of rows and your query will take longer and longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` marks in your query, `db_query()` uses `%` as a placeholder marker and performs a string replacement on things like `%s`, `%d`, `%b`, etc. They're escaped using a double percent (`%%`):

```
$result_query_totals = db_query("
  SELECT sum( field_voeding_vlees_value )
  FROM content_field_date
  LEFT JOIN content_type_expense ON content_field_date.nid = content_type_expense.nid
  WHERE addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%k:%%i:%%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) >= '2011-11-01'
  AND addtime( str_to_date( field_date_value, '%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%k:%%i:%%s' ) , '01:00:00' ) <= '2011-11-31'");
```

Comment: I was thinking that might had something to do with it but I figured not sending any variables with db_query after the string would make it clear not to replace anything. Thx.